# Como pego o nome com a extensão do arquivo em uma URL em Python?

Tags: python

Quero extrair o nome de uma imagem com sua extensão dada usa URL completa, por exemplo:

```
image_url = 'http://dominio.com.br/caminho/da/imagem/imagem.png'
```

Quero ter somente:

```
image = 'imagem.png'
```

Existe uma função pronta em Python para simplificar isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta pegar o valor de *path* da URL e dividí-la no caractere barra:

```
from urllib.parse import urlsplit

url = 'http://dominio.com.br/caminho/da/imagem/imagem.png'

parts = urlsplit(url)
paths = parts.path.split('/')

print(paths[-1])  # imagem.png
```

Comment: Nesse caso porque eu precisaria de importar o módulo `urlsplit`? A função `split` sozinha não é um método convencional para se fazer isso?

Comment: @WhoisMatt Não são euivalentes. Existem outras partes que poderiam existir na URL que a função `split` não considera. Por exemplo, na URL `http://localhost/imagem.png?cache=false#foo` ao fazer apenas o `split` você teria `imagem.png?cache=false#foo`. Com a `urlsplit` conseguimos separar cada parte da URL e analisar apenas o *path* da mesma, ignorando as *query strings* e *fragment*.

Comment: Entendi, obrigado pela dica. Vou passar a usar esse módulo então :)